# Windows ribbon split button gallery button image

Tags: delphi, ribbon

I'm using Windows Ribbon for Delphi (from http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/commands.shtml) and I have a split-button gallery, to give a drop-list of items that I can populate at runtime.

The part that isn't working is when I select an item from the gallery, its image isn't automatically transferred to the split button and I can't find a way to make it happen manually.

I've tried looking through the MS documentation but I can't see anything there that helps change the image of the button.

For the avoidance of doubt: I've checked in MSPaint and the brush selection works exactly as I want my button to work.